# Do Intersection Observer Animation and Hover effects not work together?

Tags: javascript, css, intersection-observer

I'm working on a project that is using Intersection Observer to add animation to an element's style upon entry. However, what I'm noticing is that the `: hover` attribute no longer works when I apply the style. Am I doing this wrong, or, are these two not compatible? On the JS Fiddle, I've commented out the `hover` attribute by default. Try uncommenting it and see what happens.

I've tried `banner.classList.add(/new class in here/)` but that method also took away the `:hover` as well.
**DEMO:**
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sackadelic/aw1zv7nh/14/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

disable animation on hover because animations has a higher specificity

```js
const options = {
  root: null,
  threshold: 1,
};

const banner = document.querySelector('.product-banner');

const observerAnim = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {

  entries.forEach(entry => {

    if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
      return;
    }
    banner.style.animation = '1s ease-in-out home-page-fade';
    banner.style.animationFillMode = 'forwards';
    observer.unobserve(banner);
  });

}, options);

observerAnim.observe(banner);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  min-height: 2000px;
}

img.product-banner {
  opacity:0;
  position: relative;
  top: 1000px;
  -moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

@keyframes home-page-fade {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(50%);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


img.product-banner:hover {
  animation: none !important;
  opacity: 0.8;
  transform: scale(0.9);
  -moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;

}
```

```html
<h1>
    Scroll Effect
  </h1>

  <img class="product-banner" src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/bQgcMwEnyhFu6ASuUFrtsn-1024-80.jpg" width="300">
```

Comment: Ah interesting. Did not know that! Thanks so much for the help on this.